# React JS - Blog and Blog Detail Page URL Step

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I want to make a structure where I want to show blogs and blog details on React JS side. I want to get Blog and Blog Details from blog-database.ts and blog-detail.database.ts files.

There will be only one component for Blog Detail and I want to show this component for each url specified in blog-database.

I want to go to the detail pages with "Continue Reading" on the blog page. How should I do the structure here?

Thank you very much in advance.

**blog-database.ts**

```
export default [
{
    comments: 3,
    url: '/blog/blog-detail/test',
    imgUrl: '/assets/images/products/blog-1.png',
    createdAt: '24 Feb 2020',
    title: 'Art of Keeping Home Minimal & Organised.',
    description: 'Maecenas leo ante, gravida vel lectus ac, iaculis lobortis enim. Proin nec orci nec nisl consequat molestie quis sit amet elit. Ut venenatis dignissim diam in auctor.',
},
{
    comments: 3,
    url: '/blog/blog-detail/test2',
    imgUrl: '/assets/images/products/blog-1.png',
    createdAt: '24 Feb 2020',
    title: 'Art of Keeping Home Minimal & Organised.',
    description: 'Maecenas leo ante, gravida vel lectus ac, iaculis lobortis enim. Proin nec orci nec nisl consequat molestie quis sit amet elit. Ut venenatis dignissim diam in auctor.',
 },
 ]
```

**blog-detail-database.ts**

```
export default [
{
    title: 'Art of Keeping Home Minimal & Organised',
    content: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.',
    imgUrl: '/assets/images/products/blog-1.png',
},
]
```

Component **BlogCard1.tsx**. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VvVX.jpg)

```
interface BlogCard1Props {
 url: string
 title: string
 imgUrl: string
 comments: number
 createdAt: string
 description: string
}

 const BlogCard1: FC<BlogCard1Props> = ({
 url,
 title,
 imgUrl,
 comments,
   createdAt,
   description,
}) => {
   // common icon style
   const iconStyle = { color: 'grey.600', mr: '0.3rem', fontSize: '1rem' }

  return (
    <Box>
       <LazyImage
        src={imgUrl}
        width={588}
        height={272}
       layout="responsive"
    sx={{
      '&:hover': {
        transition: '0.3s ease-in-out',
        transform: 'scale(1.1)',
        cursor: 'pointer',
      },
    }}
  />
  <Box py="1.5rem">
    <H3 lineHeight={1.3} color="secondary.900">
      {title}
    </H3>
    <FlexBox alignItems="center" mt="5px">
      <FlexBox alignItems="center" mr="1.5rem">
        <AccessTime sx={iconStyle} />
        <Paragraph>{format(new Date(createdAt), 'dd MMMM, yyyy')}</Paragraph>
      </FlexBox>

      <FlexBox alignItems="center">
        <CommentOutlined sx={iconStyle} />
        <Paragraph>{comments} comments</Paragraph>
      </FlexBox>
    </FlexBox>

    <Paragraph mt="1.2rem" mb="0.7rem">
      {description}
    </Paragraph>

    <NavLink2 title="CONTINUE READING" url={url} />
  </Box>
</Box>
)
}
export default BlogCard1
```

Page **BlogDetail.ts**

```
const BlogDetail: FC = () => {

const [blogList, setBlogList] = useState<any[]>([])

return(

    <NavbarLayout>
         <Grid container spacing={3}>

           
        </Grid>
        
        <SectionBlogArticle
            title = "More Posts"
        />
    </NavbarLayout>
    )
 }

  export default BlogDetail
```